MySQL UPDATE IGNORE opposite?
I would like to update some records. There's a chance it'll create a UNIQUE key error. In this case I would like the update to win over the previous record. How would I do this?

Unclear. Create small example (CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO, 2-3 rows, 2 UPDATEs where one of them produces an error, and desired data state after each UPDATE with explanations).

Maybe you need in simple REPLACE INTO?

I don't think you can do it with any special syntax. Do it with a transaction. First change the other row that your update would conflict with (this may change zero rows if there is no conflict). Then do your update. Finally, commit.
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE mytable SET unqColumn = NULL WHERE unqColumn = 'abc';
UPDATE mytable SET unqColumn = 'abc' WHERE id = 1234;
COMMIT;


Please show us an example; it seems like an odd thing to be doing.
See also upsert / IODKU.  INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ...  will either update if a UNIQUE key matches, else update.
